# Redux state undefined when mapping state to props in react

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I am trying to map the state of my form to the props of my LoginForm component and the state is showing as `undefined`.

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import { reduxForm, getFormValues } from 'redux-form/immutable';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { logUserIn } from '../../actions/authentication';
import { VALID_EMAIL_REGEX } from '../../config/app_config';
import LoginForm from './LoginForm';

const FORM_ID = 'loginForm';

export class LoginFormContainer extends React.Component {

  static propTypes = {
    handleSubmit: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    submitting: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    loginAction: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    values: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  };

  performLogin = (params) => {
    const { loginAction } = this.props;
    const credentials = {
      email: params.email,
      password: params.password,
    };
    loginAction(credentials, '/home');
  }

  render() {
    const { handleSubmit, submitting, values, ...others } = this.props;
    console.log(values); // <--- undefined
    return (
      <LoginForm
        handleSubmit={ handleSubmit }
        loginFunction={ this.performLogin }
        submitting={ submitting }
        {...others}
      />
    );
  }
}

// there is a validate method here

LoginFormContainer = reduxForm({
  form: FORM_ID, // <--- loginForm
  validate,
})(LoginFormContainer);

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
const values = getFormValues(FORM_ID)(state);
  return {
    values,
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
  loginAction: logUserIn,
})(LoginFormContainer);
```

HERE IS THE LoginForm component:

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import { Field, Form } from 'redux-form/immutable';
import { getClassName } from '../../utils/forms';
import { Link } from 'react-router';
// import { checkButtonDisabled } from '../../utils/forms';

const renderInput = ({ input, label, type, meta: { touched, error } }) => {
  return (
    <div className={ getClassName(touched, error) }>
      <label className="form-control-label">
        { label }&nbsp;
        {touched && error &&
         <span className="error">{ error }</span>}
      </label>
      <input
        { ...input }
        className="form-control form-control-success"
        type={ type }
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default class LoginForm extends React.Component {

  static propTypes = {
    handleSubmit: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    loginFunction: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    submitting: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  };

  render() {
    const {
      handleSubmit,
      loginFunction,
      submitting } = this.props;
    return (
      <Form id="loginForm" onSubmit={ handleSubmit(loginFunction.bind(this)) }>
        <fieldset>
          <Field
            name="email"
            component={renderInput}
            type="text"
            placeholder="example@exampledomain.com"
            label="Email address"
          />
          <Field
            name="password"
            component={renderInput}
            type="password"
            placeholder="your password"
            label="Password"
          />
        </fieldset>
        <button
          type="submit"
          className="btn btn-primary"
          disabled={ submitting }
        >
          Log In
        </button>&nbsp;
        <Link to="/forgot-password">Forgot Password?</Link>
      </Form>
    );
  }
}
```

If I just map just the state to props and console log it, it also comes back as `undefined`.

I am trying to get the values to set a condition on my submit button to be disabled but I cannot access the form state to run any of the redux-form methods to get the form values since state is undefined.

Here is a picture of the state:

[image]

anyone spot what could be the problem?

Comment: Are you sure you have `loginForm` at `form`?

Comment: I attached a picture to show the state  that shows in the console.

Comment: It's looks like you have no loginForm before your loginAction, or maby another action fill state.
Try to check, with `const values = form.loginForm && form.loginForm.values? form.loginForm.values : null; `

Answer (score 0):

is your state available anywhere in your application? if you put a debugger right after   const { form } = state; and check out what "form" is in the console, is the entire thing undefined?

if so, I would guess your problem is with the reducer setup.

if not, what does that object look like? perhaps state.loginForm.values is incorrect in some way (nested more deeply, or less deeply, or there's an array you have to filter through).

Comment: State is available in other places in my application. I state.loginForm.values is undefined because state is undefined. This component seems to be the only component that is showing state as undefined. I can show you the reducer set up of form.

Comment: `import { reducer as formReducer } from 'redux-form';
const reducer = combineReducers({
   form: formReducer,
});`

Answer (score 0):

Please try using Redux-Form `getFormValues` selector to get form values

```
import { getFormValues } from 'redux-form';
...
let values = getFormValues('myFormName')(state);
```

Also please pass props down to yor LoginForm to make sure your form has all props injected by redux-form:

```
render() {
    const { handleSubmit, submitting, values, ...others } = this.props;
    console.log(values); // <--- undefined
    return (
      <LoginForm
        handleSubmit={ handleSubmit }
        loginFunction={ this.performLogin }
        submitting={ submitting }
        {...others}
      />
    );
  }
```

Comment: I tried this but the state is undefined so the getFormValues returns undefined.

Comment: added if you wanna take a look at it

Comment: Ok so I made your changes and I am still getting undefined for values and again I think this is coming from the fact that `state` is undefined. so when I pass state into `getFormValues('loginForm')(state)` I get undefined.